# Why there is ambiguous reference to overloaded definition in this code?

Tags: scala, overloading, overload-resolution

Why there is ambiguous reference to overloaded definition in this code?

```
class A {
  def m(a1: A, o2: Any): A = {
    print("1")
    a1
  }

  def m(a1: A, a2: A): A = {
    print("2")
    a1
  }

  def m(o1: Any, o2: Any): Any = {
    print("3")
    o1
  }

  def m(o: Any): Any = {
    print("4")
    o
  }
}

class B extends A {
  def m(b1: B, o2: Any): A = {
    print("5")
    b1
  }

  override def m(a: A, o2: Any): B = {
    print("6")
    this
  }

  override def m(o1: Any, o2: Any): Any = {
    print("7")
    o1
  }

  def m(i: Int): Unit = { print("8") }
}

val a = new A
val b = new B

b.m(a, a)
```

The code above gives compile error:

> ambiguous reference to overloaded definition,
>
> [error] both method m in class B of type (a: A, o2: Any)B
>
> [error] and  method m in class A of type (a1: A, a2: A)A [error] match
>   argument types (A, B)

But my understanding is that `method m in class A of type (a1: A, a2: A)A` is more specific
than `method m in class B of type (a: A, o2: Any)B`

Any hints are appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are exactly right - the version of `m` in `A` is more specific and that is actually the problem.

Since you are actually invoking `m` on an instance of `b` (ie. `b.m(a, a)`) the compiler first checks that there is a method that matches the signature in `B`. Since `B` does indeed have a method that passes type checking (ie. `m(a: A, o2: Any): B`) so far so good. But whilst the compiler also checks the superclass `A` it finds a more specific version of `m` (ie. `m(a1: A, a2: A): A`).

The problem is you invoked `m` on an instance of `B` but you are explicitly asking the compiler to find a method that takes two arguments of type `A`. The compiler is now unsure of which version you actually intended to get executed hence the compilation error.

A better compilation message might be:

*"Hey I found a version of `m` further up the hierarchy in `A` that better meets your requirements but I see you are explicitly invoking `m` on a `B` (not an `A`) so I don't really know which one to choose now - you better check this otherwise if I just choose one you may not get the results you were after at runtime."*